# Calling Enable-SPFeature in SP2013 with CompatibilityLevel isn't working

Tags: 2013, powershell, feature

In an SP2013 environment running in SP2010 mode has anyone successfully called the Powershell command -- Enable-SPFeature while specifying the compatibility level?

Example: Enable-SPFeature -identity "FeatureID" -CompatibilityLevel 14 -url "SiteUrl"

I seem to get this error when specifying a compatibility level:
Enable-SPFeature : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

I have not successfully activated any features in 14 mode using this command and those parameters. Has anyone else experienced this?

Reference for command: http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff607803.aspx

Comment: Was the feature built in 14 Compat Mode (or does it define a compat mode at all)?

Comment: It was a SP2010 feature upgraded into SP2013, so the feature was built in 14 mode, no compatibility mpde was set.

Comment: Is the site still running in 2010 mode, or 2013 mode?  Note that you need to run Install-SPSolution with the compat level, if it wasn't built into the solution (in Visual Studio).  http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/07/22/running-sharepoint-2013-in-2010-mode-and-solution-compatibilitylevel.aspx